# Analyzing frequency of individual letters in a large body of text

Tags: string-manipulation, histograms, wolfram-alpha-queries

There are interesting histograms about the English language:

```
BarChart[Counts[StringTake[WordList[], 1]], ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[StringLength[WordList[]]]
```

[image]

I want to do something like this with the Holy Bible.

I tried:

```
numberofwords = 
Take[WolframAlpha[
"Bible", {{"Word:FamousTextData", 1}, "ComputableData"}], 1]
```

[image]

There are lists of the most frequent words:

```
WolframAlpha["Bible", IncludePods -> "MostCommonWords:FamousTextData",
AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, 
TimeConstraint -> {30, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

But I don't know how to determine the most frequent letters (alphabet).

How could I do this by using *Mathematica*?

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas

Answer (score 5):

Something like this perhaps?

```
bibOriginal = 
  Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10/pg10.txt"]; (* load the bible *)
bib = StringDrop[bibOriginal, 658]; (* drop the introductory text *)
bib = StringDrop[bib, -18733];(* drop the legalistic closeout at the end*)
bibC = Map[{#[[1]], Length[#]} &, Gather[Sort[ToLowerCase[Characters[bib]]]]];
bibC = Select[bibC, MemberQ[CharacterRange["a", "z"], #[[1]]] &]
  (*ditch punctuation and numbers*);
BarChart[bibC[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> bibC[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: bible character distribution]

```
TableForm[Sort[bibC, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]]
```

[image]

The same basic approach would probably work with the original text, so long as you were sensitive to the shift from Hebrew to Aramaic where appropriate.

Comment: Nice.  I knew I was taking too long to work out the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

We can import the bible directly from the web and convert it to a list of words fairly easily.  Here I'm going to remove the chapter/verse headings as well as extraneous punctuation marks.

```
biblewords = 
  Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10/pg10.txt"] // 
          StringSplit[#, {"*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE KING JAMES BIBLE ***", 
             "*** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE KING JAMES BIBLE ***"}] & //
         StringTrim //
        StringSplit[#, {" ", ".", "\n", ","}][[2]] & //
        Flatten //
        DeleteCases[#, ""] & //
        Select[#, (Not@
          StringMatchQ[#, 
           DigitCharacter .. ~~ ":" ~~ DigitCharacter ..] &)] & //
        StringReplace[#, (Alternatives @@ Characters[",.?:;'\"!-()*"]) -> 
          ""] & // ToLowerCase;
```

We can ask how many words and how many unique words are in the bible,

```
Length@biblewords
Length@DeleteDuplicates@biblewords
(* 790146 *)
(* 12703 *)
```

[This page](http://amazingbibletimeline.com/bible_questions/q10_bible_facts_statistics/) lists 783,137 total words and 12,143 unique words, so the above is pretty close.  Any refinements on the above importing scheme are most appreciated.  We can use [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) to get the 30 most common words and give their prevalence:

```
TableForm[
 {#1, #2/Length[biblewords] 100.0} & @@@ (Sort[
     Tally@biblewords, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[;; 30]]), 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Word", "Frequency"}}]
```

[image]

And, finally, the character count,

```
TableForm[Tally[Characters@StringJoin@biblewords], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Character", "Frequency"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try using TextWords to get words and then using DeleteStopwords to remove common words that aren't generally interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I will start by just copying how Jason B imported the bible:

```
bible = Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10/pg10.txt"];
bible = StringSplit[bible, {
     "*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE KING JAMES BIBLE \
***", "*** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE KING JAMES BIBLE ***"
     }][[2]];
```

After that I will use `WordCounts` and `LetterCounts`, which are two functions that were introduced in *Mathematica* 10.1:

```
wordcounts = WordCounts[bible];
lettercounts = LetterCounts[bible];
```

Then you can do whatever you want with those counts:

```
top30 = Take[Transpose[{Keys@wordcounts, Values@wordcounts}], 30];
TableForm[top30, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Words", "Count"}}]
```

Note that `WordCount` has the option `IgnoreCase`. If you add `IgnoreCases -> True` it will in effect convert all letters into lowercase before counting the words. `WordCount` can also be used to count n-grams.

Comment: +1 but there is a few  [words](http://i.imgur.com/4clV0Og.png),  `wordcounts // Length ` = 824